# Aurelia: using es6 import for electron + typescript

Tags: electron, aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I have an aurelia application running in electron. My source files are typescript and I have ambient [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) for electron and node.

Because I know I'm compiling for use on electron, I am transpiling my typescript to es6 and with System module loading; this means I can turn system.js's transpiler *off*. I'm using system.js and jspm because that is approach Aurelia has been pushing.

So in my ts files: I would like to be able to do:

```
import {remote} from 'electron';
```

Unfortunately, system.js does not know anything about the module *electron* and fails during runtime. TypeScript on the other hand is perfectly happy because I've set up the typings for electron and node; I get full intellisense in VSCode too.

note: if you attempt to do `var electron = require('electron');` in the header, system.js interferes with it and it fails to load. [You can place that 'require('electron')' within a class or function and it will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317818/how-to-requireelectron-when-script-is-loaded-by-system-js),  but  I don't find this ideal.

**Question:** *How can I get system.js to correctly return the 'electron' module that is only available when you run the app in electron itself?*

Answer (score 0):

A solution --hopefully there is a better way-- I've come up with is to shim the electron module for system.js and link it directly to the contents of `require('electron')`:

**electron.js**

```
System.register([], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var electron;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            electron = require('electron');
            exports_1("default", electron);

            Object.keys(electron).forEach(function (key) {
                exports_1(key, electron[key]);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

this effectively wraps the internal electron module and allows system.js to know about it. It works; but hopefully there is a more elegant/built-in way that others know of.

You don't need any mappings or changes to the typescypt as `import {remote} from 'electron'` will attempt to resolve `electron.js` as a last resort.

Comment: looks like there will be a better way with the next version of jspm: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/1837